# Big-o notation of this Pseudocode

Tags: data-structures, big-o, pseudocode

I believe that it is O(n) because there is no nested loops or dividing/multiplying going on. Am I right?

```
i <-  0
count <-  0
while(i<n)
 x  <- random()
 y <-  random()
 if (x^2 + y^2 <= 1)
   count   count+1
 i <-  i + 1
```

done
pi  <- 4*count/n

Answer (score 0):

It is O(n) because while loop runs n times.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at all the statements, this time adding some labels in brackets

```
[1] i <- 0
[2] count <- 0
[3] while(i < n)
  [3.1] x <- random()
  [3.2] y <- random()
  [3.3] if (x^2 + y^2 <= 1)
     [3.3.1] count <- count + 1
  [3.4] i <-  i + 1
```

Now let's calculate the complexity of each of the statements:

```
[1] O(1)
[2] O(1)
[3] n times
  [3.1] O(1)
  [3.2] O(1)
  [3.3] O(1)
     [3.3.1] O(1)
  [3.4] O(1)
```

So, the total complexity is

```
O(1) + O(1) + n * 4 * O(1) = O(n)
```